# Cannot find Wine after successfull install

Tags: wine

I installed Wine through App Center and nothing is wrong with that, except than when I want execute it, it doesn't find into apps menu.

Also, Wine is not present at file associations. When I try to "Open with ..." an .exe file, Wine is not found on programs list.

I tried removing it and reinstalling from terminal with `sudo apt install winehq-stable` but results are always the same.

Answer (score 5):

You have installed wine, but you may need to configure it. Please run `winecfg` in your terminal.

You may also need to use the command line to tell Wine to open an application the first time you do so.

For example, if I was trying to run "application.exe" in the downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wine application.exe
```

The application should run and should also be added to the Applications launcher.

I highly recommend that you take a look at WineHQ, which is a great online resource for using wine that not only includes well-written and thorough documentation and wiki pages, but also has an extensive database that can help you if you're having trouble with a particular Windows application.

https://www.winehq.org/help